# update validated value from a record

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I have a real problem but simple,really , i have an edit form that edits a record of a table, i have a value in it that it has to be unique ex:username,i using jquery validation plugin to validate, so i use the remote method like so:-

```
companyName: {
        required: $("input#companyRequired").val(),
            remote: "validator/checkCompanyName"
         }
```

and it enters a method from the server that checks the value from the database,here's the method to check:-

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/checkCompanyName", params = "companyName")
public @ResponseBody
String checkCompanyName(@RequestParam String companyName) {
logger.debug("checking company : " + companyName);
    if(leadService.checkCompany(companyName)==true){
        return "false";
    }
    else{
        return "true";
    }
}
```

the problem is that i want to use remote only if the user has changed the input,so what should i do?,any help would appreciated,i'am using spring mvc as a server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger validation only when user changes input value try that approach:

```
$("input#companyRequired").change(function(){
   $("input#companyRequired").validate(
      // rules here
   )
});
```

If you want to validate several elements add class "remote-check" (or come up with your name) to that fields:

```
$("input.remote-check").change(function(){
   $(this).validate(
      // rules here
   )
});
```

Comment: now i want to use this on more than one input,i tried this with another input but one works